# Are there any CDNs that can connect to custom Google NPM Artifact Registries?

Tags: npm, google-cloud-platform, cdn, google-artifact-registry

I have a public custom repo and I can access the tar file using the `curl -L -v "https://us-central1-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/npm-public/@my-scope/bucky-barnes/-/@pure-pm/bucky-barnes-0.0.1.tgz"`. The problem is I need to host the contents of the tgz similar to the site `unpkg` `unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js`. I know I could create a server that streams the tar, decompresses it and cache it; but that seems like it should be a solved problem.

Are there any CDNs that support custom registries like Google's Artifact Registry?

I see ones like https://cdn.jsdelivr.net that seem to support Github packages but I can't find any that support Google.

Comment: You _could_ use a custom reverse proxy for the service itself. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/hack-your-own-custom-domains-container-registry) is an article that explains it.

Comment: @HNeiva thank you but this doesn't really help in my use cases. I need to do things like change versions by just changing the url etc just like the CDN does. I know how to just host the file I am looking more for a unpkg clone for a custom registry.